# Do Citrus potted plants need acidic soil

Tags: houseplants, lemons, potting-soil, ph

Does Citrus Plants growing in pots, need slightly acidic soil?

I am thinking of the jasmine plant that requires, 1 teaspoon of vinegar, mixed with water, approx every 15 days, particularly during flowering season.

Should I do the same for other plants like Tangerines or lemons and give them doses of vinegar, periodically?

Answer (score 2):

Citrus species prefer a *slightly* acidic soil (pH 6 to 7) but regular application of vinegar would be over doing it. Unless the citrus was (incorrectly) potted in alkaline compost, you probably don't need to take any action to change the soil pH.

Remember that anything that goes into a plant pot and is not taken up by the plant stays there, and will accumulate if you keep adding more. If you keep adding vinegar, and eventually your poor citrus will be trying to grow in the equivalent of a moorland peat bog, more suitable for heathers, blueberries, etc.